# Check for multiple nil values in Core Data managedObject?

Tags: ios, core-data, if-statement, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I need to check if there any `nil` values in my `managedObjectContext` before saving them. At the minute I am doing tests on each key using `if` statements. I have many attributes in my `NGLS` entity, so as you can see testing each key for `nil` values doesn't seem very practical.

```
if ([_managedObjectNGLS valueForKey:@"q1"] == nil){
    [_managedObjectNGLS setValue:@"" forKey:@"q1"];
}
if ([_managedObjectNGLS valueForKey:@"q1More"] == nil){
    [_managedObjectNGLS setValue:@"" forKey:@"q1More"];
}
....

// Save managedObject
NSError *error;
[[self.managedObjectNGLS managedObjectContext] save:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", self.managedObjectNGLS);
NSLog(@"Data saved");
```

Often there are many `nil` values, which I need to change manually with many `if statements`. Is there a way to batch test all objects in my entity for nil values? And if so, is there a way to replace all of these with a set `string` at once? Thanks.

Comment: You mean something like this: `NSArray *allKeys = @[@"q1", @"q1More", etc.];for (NSString *aKey in allKeys){if ([_managedObjectNGLS valueForKey:aKey] == nil){[_managedObjectNGLS setValue:@"" forKey:aKey];}}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data includes powerful [capabilities for validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html). As part of a save, Core Data validates object properties, ensuring that only valid object are persisted.

You can implement validation rules in the [Core Data Model Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/about_cd_modeling_tool.html), or yourself in code by implementing [key-value validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Validation.html) on your managed object subclass.

For example, using the model editor you can set a property to be non-optional and provide a default value:

[image: Non optional with default]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and links to documentation, this helps a lot! I'll mark your answer as correct as I'm going to use a mixture of this plus Larme's solution (using a `for loop` in an `array`) as they are both useful for what I need. Thanks again.