# Check if single attribute in managedObjectContext is *not* nil

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uibutton, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a `ServicesViewController` with a number of `UIButtons`. The user can tap a button and has a choice to enter "Further Details" via an `UIAlertView` with `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`. If the user chooses not to add "Further Details", the `UIButton` state stays `selected` and the `key` is saved as `Yes` in my `managedObjectContext`. If they choose to add "Further Details", the `key` is still saved as `Yes`, and the "Further Details" `key` is saved as whatever `string` they enter.

The user can then navigate to another `ViewController` and back to the `ServicesViewController` when they like. I need to perform a check in the `viewDidLoad` method in the `ServicesViewController`, on the `keys` on my `managedObjectContext`. If the `UIButton` `key` is saved as "Yes", then the `UIButton` state must be highlighted. Whereas if the "Further Details" `key` is not `nil`, then the button must change state to `disabled` and can also change colour for user feedback.

Code to select the button:

```
- (IBAction)asbBtnPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        [_managedObjectNGLS setValue:@"" forKey:@"asb"];
    } else {
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        [_managedObjectNGLS setValue:@"Yes" forKey:@"asb"];
    }

    UIAlertView *qConfirm = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Additional Information"
                                                       message:@"Would you like to give additional information?"
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"Proceed", nil];
    qConfirm.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    qConfirm.tag = 2;
    if (sender.isSelected == YES) {
        [qConfirm show];
    }
}
```

If user enters "Further Details", disable button and change colour:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // ASB
    if (alertView.tag == 2) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            NSString *asbDetails = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
            [_managedObjectNGLS setValue:asbDetails forKeyPath:@"asbDetails"];
            if (asbDetails.length > 1) {
                [_asbBtn setSelected:NO];
                _asbBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(55/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:1];
                _asbBtn.enabled = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
```

Code attempting to check for `nil` value:

```
// If UIButton has been selected
if ([[_managedObjectNGLS valueForKey:@"asb"] isEqual: @"Yes"]) {
    _asbBtn.selected = YES;

    // If "Further Details" is empty
} else if ([_managedObjectNGLS valueForKey:@"asbDetails"] == nil) {
    // Do nothing
} else {
    // Else "Further Details" must be populated, so change colour & disable button
    _asbBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(55/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:1];
    _asbBtn.enabled = FALSE;
    NSLog(@"asbDetails not empty");
}
```

I realise this is not the best approach (mainly because it isn't working!), idealy I would like to check if the `key` isn't `nil` by perfoming a `!=` test, but this doesn't work either. I didn't want to go down the road of a `fetchRequest` because I have many buttons and many keys to test, and each button must stay separate, so I don't think I can use a `for loop` either as that would alter all buttons? Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be interested with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893279/check-for-multiple-nil-values-in-core-data-managedobject

Comment: That's actually another question I posted haha :p That was checking for multiple `nil` values, now I need to check for single NOT `nil` values (I have updated the title as it was misleading). I will have another look at `Key-Value coding` as it looks helpful, but I'll leave this question up to see if anyone knows a good solution based on my code. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have had to come up with somewhat of a workaround. There is probably a better solution, but this will work for now:

```
- (void)isInterested {
    // If valueForKey is "yes", keep button in selected state
    // If ...Details key isn't empty, disable button & change colour

    // ASB
    if ([[_managedObjectNGLS valueForKey:@"asb"] isEqual: @"Yes"]) {
        _asbBtn.selected = YES;
    }
    NSString *asbDetails = [_managedObjectNGLS valueForKey:@"asbDetails"];
    if (asbDetails.length > 0) {
        _asbBtn.selected = NO;
        _asbBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(55/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:1];
        _asbBtn.enabled = FALSE;
        // NSLog(@"asbDetails is not empty");
    }

    // More buttons
}
```

I am calling the `isInterested` method in my `ServicesViewController` `viewDidLoad` - this means that every time this `view` is loaded, the `isInterested` method will perform the required checks and set the `UIButton` in it's correct state.